# TCoolBar bands growing when resizing form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl, window-resize

In a Delphi XE2 VCL Forms Application, I've placed a `TCoolBar` on the top of my main form. I've added two `TCoolBand`s to this bar. Then I inserted a `TToolBar` into each of these two bands. Each toolbar has a few buttons.

The problem is, when I'm resizing my form horizontally (both in design-time and run-time), the bands grow in width, regardless of if I'm making the form larger or smaller. Even when making my form smaller, the bands grow, until the second one is eventually pushed out of view.

Why does this happen and how do I stop it from happening?

Comment: Adjust them [`MinWidth`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCoolBand.MinWidth) property. Though I don't get this behavior, it resolves the minimum size you need to have for your toolbar. I don't like personally this sort of controls. They're not as cool as it seems.

Comment: @TLama, Just tried it and it didn't work :(

Comment: It's not a solution for that (in my view strange) resizing. It just keeps the minimum width you need to have to see your toolbar. The resizing itself is *hardcoded* in the `TCoolBar` and you'll have no chance without a subclass to change it, I'd say. Sorry, I'm busy to go deeper right now (maybe later I can take a look).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the only solution (thanks to Ludek Stauber) is to patch Vcl.ComCtrls.pas. At the end of method TCoolBar.GetCaptionSize add the two lines to handle IE6 and newer:

```
  { The grip size in IE4 is 3 pixels narrower than IE3 }
  if GetComCtlVersion < ComCtlVersionIE4 then
    Inc(Result, GripSizeIE3)
  // begin handle IE6
  else if GetComCtlVersion >= $0006000A {ComCtlVersionIE610} then
    Inc(Result, 4 {GripSizeIE610})
  // end handle IE6
  else
```

Comment: Here is [`the source`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=70868) of this error and its fix.